# SSRS 2017 Web Portal Forms Authentication access Issue

Tags: reporting-services, forms-authentication

I have implemented a custom authentication (based on Forms authentication) using Microsoft sample (https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample).

It is sample for SSRS/SQL Server 2017. In my case the reporting Services are installed on a web test server with a domain address accessible from intranet network. The database engine is installed on a second server. On the web server we also have IIS installed.

It looks that it works fine except accessing the Web Portal.
When accessing the Web portal (https://somedomain/reports) I am always redirected to the logon.aspx page even though I am already authenticated (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns true and User.Identity.Name returns correct user name on logon_aspx.page_load). The Forms authentication cookie is set. When I am authenticated I return from the Page_Load because otherwise I would end up with infinite redirection loop.

But I noticed that I can access the reports using the Report Server Service (i.e. https://somedomain/ReportServer):

[image]

I can click a report and it will be displayed.

Furthermore I can connect to the Reporting Services using SSMS and Forms authentication:

[image]

And I can access the Reporting Services properties. So I have full access.
I am connecting using a user which have all permissions, i.e Authorization.IsAdmin is always true (see Authorization class in the sample). This class implements IAuthorizationExtension.

But I noticed that when accessing the web portal no Authorization.CheckAccess method is invoked at all!  So this migt be a clue. Only methods from AuthenticationExtension class are invoked. Here is my custom logs from this class:

*Invoked SetConfiguration.

Invoked GetUserInfo.

GetUserInfo. Setting user identity. Authenticated: 'True', type: 'Forms', user name: 
Invoked SetConfiguration.

Invoked GetUserInfo 2.

GetUserInfo. Setting user identity. Authenticated: 'True', type: 'Forms', user name: 
Invoked SetConfiguration.

Invoked GetUserInfo.

GetUserInfo. Setting user identity. Authenticated: 'True', type: 'Forms', user name:*

I have turned on extended logging for the Reporting Services (also including HTTP) but there is no error.

I also have local (developer) implementation of this sample on my local machine and it works fine. I can access the web portal (although I have tested it accessing it from local).

So this is happening only on the test server. And this is happening for http and https (no matter which protocol is used).

I also compared logs from the local version to the test version but I did not found anything interesting.

So /reports requests is redirected to the logon.aspx even though forms auth cookie is set:

[image]

If I clear cookies I get few more requests until the cookie is set but the last request to /reports should be successful (as it is on the local env) but in my case it redirects back to the logon.aspx.

I have spent already two days troubleshooting this issue (trying various things) but with no luck. 
Could anybody help me with this?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar situation as you described, although before that everything worked on ssrs 2017! Launched last updated 9/12/2018, version 14.0.600.892, and lo and behold, it works!! I advise you to try to update SSRS 2017 to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution is in the reporting services configuration manager to change the web Service URL and the Report Manager URL, these should not be the same and the url that you must access must be the one that you configure as Report manager URL, sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. I just reinstalled the SSRS and this helped. So it looks that my installation was corrupted somehow.